# How many tables and databases can I create in Android sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

How many databases can I create in one instance of sqlite?

In one Database how many tables can I create in sqlite?

What is the maximum size of data that a Table or column can hold?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How many databases can i create in one application?

As many as you want, within the limits of available disk space.

> in one Database how many tables can i create?

A billion or so, though you will run out of disk space first.

> and what was the maximum size of data that can holds a Table or a column?

For Android, as much disk space as you have available.

See: http://sqlite.org/limits.html

Answer (score 1):

you can create multiple database, tables in your application and 
 the size of database is depends on your sd-card size
because  SQLite database stores in `Environment.getDataDirectory() + /data/<Package       Name>/databases.`

you can check the size of database by using this code

```
SQLiteDatabase db;

// ...

long size = new File(db.getPath()).length();
```

Comment: i am asking what was the maximum size of the database in android.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no limit of the database size, instead you can limit you database size programmitically using setMaximumSize(DB_SIZE). As long as your device has sufficient storage your database will grow according the size of data.

Refer this thread : http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a743a3a5a6f5f353?pli=1